# What can a prepositional phrase modify adverbially?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbials

I wonder what prepositional phrase can modify when it as an adverb phrase?

I've learned about adjective + preposition these day, and I got confused.

see - It's very generous of you to bring me a present. 
( I know to bring me a present is an adverb tell us why it's very generous. But how about "of you" ?  )

Comment: This website might suit you better: http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It" is a precursory subject or mere indicator that the real subject is at the end: to bring me a present. You could also say: To bring me a present | is generous of you.

Adjectives can have a complement.   [Link](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/what-is-an-adsjective-complement.html) You have to fill in " What is an adjective complement?" in the search field.

Comment: So the prepositional phrase can modify an adjective when it as an adverbial phrase right?

Comment: I don't see it this way. When you learn "to be angry at something /someone" what has "at sth/someone" to do with adverb or adverbial? It is just the complement that is possible when you use "angry".

Comment: So that is an adjective complement?? what is an adjective complement?

Comment: Didn't you read the examples of the link?

Comment: And I wonder that the prepositional phrase can just modify verbs when it as adverbial phrase? Or it can modify adjective or adverb? Cause in most time, I only see prepositional phrase as adverb just modify a verb.

Comment: Yea I have opened it but Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for. It might be an old link or maybe it moved. It said

Comment: Oh, I see. Fill in  What is an adjective complement? in the search field.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer! If I may one more question. The website say the adjective complement always follows the adjective it complements and it is a noun clause or a prepositional phrase. I'm confused again! what is a preposition function as when it as an adjective complement? an adverb or an adjective?

Comment: Sorry,  I don't quite understand  your problem and don't want to run into a grammar course about English grammar terminology. I'm German and used to traditional Latin terms and I have my own problems with the English terminology which I often find confusing. So I suggest that you think about your new problem and ask a new question. But one question at a time. If necessary make several posts.